# More than one operation on each parameter of the for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Is there a syntax to include multiple initialization or final expression on a `for` loop in javascript?

For instance initialize two variables, or increment two variables.

I don't see anything about it on the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: Do you mean something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674700/regarding-javascript-for-loop-voodoo?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348792/multiple-counters-in-javascript-for-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for....

```
for (var i = 0, a = 1; i < 10; i++, a += 2) {
    console.log(i, a);
}
```

output:

```
0 1
1 3
2 5
3 7
4 9
5 11
6 13
7 15
8 17
9 19
```